# there exists a continuous function $g$ on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f-g|<\epsilon$. Can we say that $g$ is uniform

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, uniform-continuity

Let $f$ be integrable over $\mathbb{R}$, and let $\epsilon>0$. Then there exists a continuous function $g$ on $\mathbb{R}$ which vanishes outside a bounded set and $\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f-g|<\epsilon$. Can we say that $g$ is uniformly continuous? why or why not?

Comment: any continuous function on $\mathbb R$ vanishing outside a bounded set is uniformly continuous

Comment: @zhw. A continuous function on a bounded set is certainly bounded, but may not be uniform. Why would "vanishing outside" make the difference?

Comment: first no, a continuous function on a bounded set need not be bounded. Second, we are given a function continuous on $\mathbb R$ that vanishes outside of a bounded set. That will be uniformly continuous.

Comment: @zhw. Got it. Thank you.